# Pedersen 2.5.6(f) - Extreme points of the ball of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

In Pedersen's "Analysis Now" (2.5.6, page 72) he mentions the following fact:

"Consider the convex set of holomorphic functions $f$ on an open subset $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $\|f\|_\infty \leq 1$. The extreme points are the functions

$$ f(z) = \frac{\alpha}{z-z_0} $$
where $z_0 \notin \Omega$ and $|\alpha| = d(z_0, \Omega)$. The strategy in 2.5.5 is capitalized in the Cauchy integral formula."

Is this true (up to some modification), and does someone have a reference for a proof of it? I think you need to adjust it so that $z_0 \notin \bar{\Omega}$, since otherwise it says that $0$ is an extreme point. I also don't think this can be all of the extreme points, since this is implying $1$ is not an extreme point.

Comment: the above is weird - for the unit disc it is well known that there are a gazillion of extreme points in the unit ball of $H^{\infty}$ (all inner functions are and more - hence all finite/infinite Blaschke products and all positive singular measures on the unit circle which correspond to singular inner functions); there is a classical theorem that characterizes all such in terms of the integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\log (1-|f(e^{it}|)dt =- \infty$, where $f(e^{it})$ is as usual the non-tangential limit of $f$ which exists ae; the proof is fairly straitghtforward

Comment: @Conrad do you know a reference/name for the theorem? That seems like a place to start

Comment: it is a classic result and is not that hard to prove since if the condition doesn't hold, one can take the outer function given by $|g(e^{i\theta})|=1-|f(e^{i\theta}|$ ($|g| \le 1$ is non zero precisely when that integral is finite and then $|f \pm g| \le 1$ and $f$ is obviously the average of those two, while conversely, we need $g$ as above zero, so the integral is $-\infty$; a very useful reference is K Hoffman Banach Spaces of Analytic Functions https://www.amazon.com/Banach-Spaces-Analytic-Functions-Mathematics/dp/0486458741

Comment: Thanks for the reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the consensus is that there is a typo (thanks to @Conrad for the comments). If you look at something like the disc algebra and make some edits to the statement you might be able to recreate what Pedersen was trying to claim.

Comment: as an aside - thinking  a bit more about this, I think the author was referring to functions that are holomorphic on the closed unit disc (in other words in an open neighborhood of the closed disc that may depend on the function, or equivalently the radius of convergence of the Taylor series at zero is strictly greater than one) for which the result holds since there is a theorem by Wolff that describes all such as normal series of partial fractions based outside the disc from which the result follows